# get data from table and from relative foreign tables in SQL

Tags: sql, laravel, controller

Hi have a text search input that looks for matching records in the DB and gets all the data from a table:

let's say like this:

```
$q = Input::get('items');

        $q = "\"" . "($q)" . "\"";

        $items = DB::table('my_items')->whereRaw(

            'MATCH(item_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)',

            array($q)

        )->get();
```

So I get all the items in the DB from my textsearch, then I send the result as json to some script that updates my page with the items:

```
return Response()->json($items);
```

The relations are:

My_item:

```
public function brand(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Brand', 'id', 'brand_id');
    }
```

Brand:

```
public function My_item(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\My_item');

    }
```

Now the problem here is that in `'my_items'` table I have some data as IDs that reference foreign tables.
For example I will have a `'brand_id'` that for example references a `'brands'` table where I can have information regarding the brand.
So for example I could have `brand_id = 3` that means `'Microsoft'` in my brands table `(id = 3, name = microsoft)`.
Now what I need to do is not only passing the brand_id to my view but also the actual information (name), in this case Microsoft so that I can  put that info in the item description.
But, how can I get that information before sending with that query? Is there some sort of flag I can use in the query like `$items = DB::table bla bla with foreign`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can simplify your search query to something like this:

```
My_item::where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();
```

Now, assign relations the relation to your other tables in your Models. Then you can get all information using the following syntax:

```
My_item::with('brand')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();
```

Read more about relations here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: your `DB::table('my_items')::where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();` gives `syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)`. This one works `DB::table('my_items')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();` ... the one `DB::table('my_items')->with('brand')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();` results in 500 internal server error

Comment: Did you add all the relations?

Comment: Yes the relations are there but the query builder (DB::) doesn't work like that. I dropped the method and used the model, check my answer.

Comment: Can you update your model relations too in the question?

Answer (score 0):

this way works, `DB::` method is dropped for:

```
$items = My_item::with('brand')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();
```

this one doesn't:

```
DB::table('my_items')::with('brand')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%")->get();
```

Comment: What's the error you get when you perform the second query?

Comment: first of all phpstorm tells: "incorrect access to static class member".. when performing the query the error is: "FatalErrorException in ShoeSearchController.php line 111:
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)" .. sorry not even the query, the page doesn't load at all and that error is displayed.

Comment: `My_item::with('brand')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', '%$q%')->get();`   This should work actually.

Comment: Yes, I already told that it works. The one with query builder doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you use query builder when you have eloquent in laravel?

Comment: What's the point of asking? You modifed the query builder one in a way it can't work. The eloquent one works, thanks for your input.

Comment: I did update my answer sometimes ago. Did you see that?